# Interrupt Threads with a JButton

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, button, jbutton

I'm currently having lessons about Java threads in my college,and today's exercise was about creating two threads.
 **Thread A** prints random numbers from 1 to 9 with no sleep, and **Thread B** from 1000 to 9999 with 50 sleep, it's an infinite loop til I decide to press the **stop button** which is a JButton that **interrupts both threads**.
Thing is, I'm having some trouble trying to stop the threads with one button, and mainly trying to find out how to work it out ,  and how to create an actionEvent for that purpose.

This is the code I have so far:

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class RandomNumbers extends Thread {
    long time;
    long min;
    long max;
    private JFrame window;
    private JButton stopButton;

    public RandomNumbers(long min, long max, long time) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.time = time;
        new Window();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println((int) ((Math.random() * max) + min));
                Thread.sleep(time);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("I was interrupted!");
        }
    }

    public class Window {
        public Window() {
            window = new JFrame("Stop Button");
            stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
            stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    // ThreadA.interrupt(); //problem in here , what to do ? //****
                    // ThreadB.interrupt();

                }
            });

            window.getContentPane().add(stopButton);
            window.setSize(100, 100);
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Thread threadB = new RandomNumbers(1, 9, 50);
        Thread threadA = new RandomNumbers(1000, 8999, 0);
        threadB.start();
        threadA.start();
    }
}
```

Also there's another problem on this code where it'll create **2 stop buttons** , 1 for each thread, as it's no the constructor.. I'm kinda lost so I need some guidance here.
Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot !

Comment: You create two threads, and each thread creates a window. So that'll land you two windows. Also, to debug it'll be nice to know the current thread's name:  `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +":"+ (int) ((Math.random() * max) + min));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't passed an instance of your thread into your GUI but rather are creating **two separate** GUI's one for each thread which is a bit kooky. Keep your separate parts of your program separate, probably in separate classes. For example:

- create a class called MyRunnable that implements Runnable and does the threading part of the code.
- Create an array of them for your main program/GUI.
- Create an array of thread to hold run the Runnables.
- Then in the ActionListener, interrupt your threads.

e.g. (just the GUI part),

```
public class ThreadTest extends JPanel {
   private JButton button = new JButton(new ButtonAction());
   private MyRunnable[] runnables = { 
         new MyRunnable("thread 1", 1, 9, 50), 
         new MyRunnable("thread 2", 1000, 8999, 1) };
   private Thread[] threads = new Thread[runnables.length];

   public ThreadTest() {
      add(button);
      for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
         threads[i] = new Thread(runnables[i]);
         threads[i].setName(runnables[i].getName());
         threads[i].start();
      }
   }

   private class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
      public ButtonAction() {
         super("Stop Threads");
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         for (Thread thread : threads) {
            if (thread != null && thread.isAlive()) {
               thread.interrupt();
            }
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ThreadTest");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new ThreadTest());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```